# Download File from DataTable

Tags: c#, file, datatable, download, directory

I'm trying to develop some kind of FTP program in school. The service they provided me to download files from their server only downloads one file at a time and if I try to download a folder it returns a blank file. How is it possible to create some kind of system to download the whole directory (even the files inside the directory of the selected directory)?
This is what I use to get the files:

```
foreach (ListViewItem cadaItem in listView2.SelectedItems)
        {
            string type = listView2.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
            MessageBox.Show(type);

            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[666666];
            byte[] hash = new byte[666666];


            if (type != "")
            {
                servDin.GetFileMD5Async("", "", Vars.pastaLocal + @"\" + cadaItem.Text, hash, fileBytes);

                using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(Vars.pastaLocal + @"\" + Convert.ToString(cadaItem.Text)))
                {
                    file.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                }
            }
```

I wanted to use a datatable to get the filenames and download the files from there. is it possible?

Thank You

Comment: The FTP method has an option to get directories.  See codeproject : https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/245306/FTP-Sub-Folders-get-files-from-sub-folders-also

Comment: I'm not using the FTP method tho

Comment: When downloading multiple binaries at one time you need pass a byte count of each binary.  So normally you would add a header to each binary which would include the name and size.